# Creating XML RSS from Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

What I'm trying to do is create a stored procedure that will generate an xml that looks like the following.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">
    <rowset>
    <row>
      <title>myTitle</title>
      <description>myDescription</description>
      <georss:point>myLat myLon</georss:point>
     </row>
     ...
    </rowset>
    </rss>
```

Which I have the following to generate

```
 SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(q'!
 SELECT trim(sitedesc)  AS "title", 
    '<a href="../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLIST&sitecode='||trim(sitecode)||'&forceDB=">'||trim(siteabbrev)||'</a>'   AS "description", 
    trim(latitude)|| ' ' ||trim(longitude) AS "georss:point"
   FROM LS
   WHERE sold <> 1
    !') FROM dual;
```

Output looks like this

```
   <ROW>
   <title>Tipton Facilities</title>
   <description>&lt;a href=&quot;../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLISTnull=USINTI01null=&quot;&gt;TIP1&lt;/a&gt;</description>
   <georss:point>40.286008 -86.058054</georss:point>
   </ROW>
```

In the 'description' I want to have a link to another page, I understand xml has certain reserved characters like `> < & %` it looks like the output automatically converts the reserved characters into it's entity reference accordingly.

The problem however is that the program thinks `sitecode` and `forcedb` in the url are variables, when they are not, and they get dropped from the results.

The url should be: `&lt;a href="../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLIST&amp;sitecode=USINTI01&amp;forceDB="&gt;`

But it's `&lt;a href=&quot;../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLISTnull=USINTI01null=&quot;&gt;`

Will I need to type out the url with `ctr()` function to get the desired output?

**`SET SCAN OFF` fixes my variable question.

Updating sample code per below comments.**

```
             SELECT XMLELEMENT("rss", XMLATTRIBUTES('http://www.georss.org/georss' AS "xmlns:georss"),
                XMLELEMENT("channel",
                             XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("item",
                                               XMLFOREST(title AS "title",
                                                          description AS "description",
                                                          point AS "georss:point"))))).EXTRACT('/*')
             FROM (SELECT trim(longitude) || ' ' || trim(latitude) AS point, 
      '../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLIST&sitecode='||trim(sitecode)||'&forceDB=">'||trim(siteabbrev)||'</a>' AS description, 
      trim(sitedesc) AS title
      FROM ls 
      WHERE sold <>1
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've run this from sqlplus. sqlplus by default sees an ampersand as a substitution character.  to disable this, run in sqlplus "set scan off". GUIs will have an equivalent settting to stop checking for subsitution variables.

your rss would be much easier and neater if you used XMLX functions (XMLForest, XMLElement).

eg

```
SQL> select xmlelement("rss", xmlattributes('http://www.georss.org/georss' as "xmlns:georss"),
  2                     xmlelement("rowset",
  3                                 xmlagg(xmlelement("row",
  4                                                    xmlforest(title as "title",
  5                                                               description as "description",
  6                                                               point as "georss:point"))))).extract('/*')
  7    from (select 'myLat myLon' point, 'asd' description, 'foo' title
  8             from dual
  9           union all
 10           select 'myLat2 myLon2' point,
 11                 '<a href="../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLIST&sitecode=USINTI01&forceDB=">' description,
 12                 'tetert' title
 13             from dual);

XMLELEMENT(RSS,XMLATTRIBUTES
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <rowset>
    <row>
      <title>foo</title>
      <description>asd</description>
      <georss:point>myLat myLon</georss:point>
    </row>
    <row>
      <title>tetert</title>
      <description>&lt;a href=&quot;../scripts/fmiinfo.asp?file_code=_BLDGLIST&amp;sitecode=USINTI01&amp;forceDB=&quot;&gt;</description>
      <georss:point>myLat2 myLon2</georss:point>
    </row>
  </rowset>
</rss>


SQL>
```

Comment: thank you, I did try to use XML functions to get better results.  Have tried your suggestion but it doesn't run.  I see that both select statements are from dual, and there is a union all.  Could you explain this?  I can start a new question if needed.

Comment: @gSaenz the dual bit was just to form sample data. What errors do you get? Paste your output

Comment: Was trying to concatenate and had my ' in the wrong place, fixed it. Though I did it without the `UNION ALL` clause, still dont understand what that did, pasted above is my query

Comment: @gSaenz it was just sample data. it gave me two rows of sample data `select one row union all select another row` thats all(i did it to show the working of xmlagg)